# Is there a way to access the device IMEI without having reference to the Activity or Context?

Tags: android, android-context

I'm a bit puzzled here.

From all the resources I've read on how to get the device id (IMEI) in Android, it seems that there is no way to get it without having a reference to the Activity or the Activity Context.

Is that true?

Could there be another way? Some static system methods to help perform this easy task?

Where is the logic behind this decision?

is this the only option out there?

```
TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String imei = mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
```

with the following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Thanks,

Ita

Comment: The irony is that what you are getting from context is the value of a public static string constant ("phone" iirc) but assuming that it will always have the value it does today is not really proper.

Comment: Will it be possible to launch a sub Activity from the library that doesn't have any access to the Context? In that case will it be possible to communicate with this Activity and have it check for the IMEI of the device? (check against a predefined IMEI list of-course)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in `Application.onCreate()` and store the IMEI in a `public static String`.

Comment: Yes I know.. the problem is that I want to create a stand alone library that performs this task.The Activity is behind my reach unless I ask for its context in my API. I don't want to do that. 10x anyway